# How parse a simple string that contains xml tags (need to read two tags)

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I'm using a class to read the content of a web page (it contains text like xml) and save it in a string variable. It is working correctly. What i need to do now is found the value of some tags inside this string.
So this is the class that read the page. As you can see there is the method "onPostExecute" that is where i need to read the tags.

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); //create a new http client
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url); //create a new http request passing a valid url
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet); //try to execute the http get request
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent(); //prepare the input stream to read the bytes of the request
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s; //until is present a line to read, the response variable store the value of the lines
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("MyApp", "Download Exception : " + e.toString()); //Print the error if something goes wrong
            }
        }
        Log.i("RESPONSE",""+response);
        return response; //return the response
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        result = webPage.doInBackground(initConfiguration); //take the result from the DownloadWebPageTask class
        Log.i("RESULT",""+result);
        //find the price and format value from the result            
    }

}
```

So now what can i do? Have you some suggestions? Have i to use some kind of xml parser? I need something easy to use because i have only to read one or two tags.
This is an example of the string that contains the tags:

```
<products currency="EUR">
<product id="1" width="1796" height="1228" name="10 X 15 cm">
  <prices>
    <price fixfee="0.5" from="50" price="0.65" />
    <price fixfee="0.10" from="20" price="0.70" />
    <price fixfee="0.10" from="0" price="0.75" />
  </prices>
</product>
<product id="2" width="3626" height="2422" name="20 X 30 cm">
  <prices>
    <price fixfee="0.5" from="50" price="0.75" />
    <price fixfee="0.10" from="20" price="0.80" />
    <price fixfee="0.10" from="0" price="0.100" />
  </prices>
</product>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) library. here is good example that can serve you:

```
String html = "<?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\" encoding=\\\"UTF-8\\\">" + 
            "       <book>" + 
            "          <string> book name </string>" + 
            "          <array>" + 
            "             <string> Name1 </string>" + 
            "             <string> Name2 </string>" + 
            "          </array>" + 
            "       </book></xml>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());

    Element book = doc.select("book").first();

    Element bookName = book.getElementsByTag("string").first();

    Elements array = book.getElementsByTag("array"); 

    for (Element e : array.select("string")) {
      //....
    }
```

However Android today has his one parser [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html).

So you can try both options,

Hope it will help you

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but if possible i prefer using something official given from android sdk

Comment: see my second option, `XmlPullParser`

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the incoming xml using android default xml parser. better to use Simple XML parser take a look [here](http://simple.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: yes i want use the official parser given from the sdk. Do you mean in this case the XmlPullParser? Or something else?

Comment: Something else which gives you JABX type annotation based xml parsing. take a look on the tutorial. I personally use it.